# How to block USB storage devices in user space of Linux operating system programatically

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have to develop functionality wherein, when USB storage device is connected to Linux machine, my password window will popup. And if user enters the password correctly, device will be proceeded for mounting. If password is wrong device should not be accessible to user. It's like endpoint protection for Linux operating systems.

How can we achieve this in Linux user space only?

Here I don't want to go for kernel mode programming as it is very much time consuming and involves issues related to distribution wide compatibility.

Also the solution should be generic to all kernel versions and Linux distributions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [polkit](http://linux.die.net/man/8/polkit) does?

Comment: "**my** password window ..." - Do not use homebrew stuff! Instead use PAM.

Comment: if you want password you better do encryption. blocking fs from mounting is too easily hacked

Comment: Kernel allows only root to mount devices. So if you want the user to be able to mount a device, you need a user-space program that will get root permissions anyway.

Comment: There is no universal Linux USB automounting mechanism, so there is no solution matching your specs.

Comment: But, I would suppose you would write a GUI app, which would listen to relevant DBUS messages sent by whatever daemon, when a new disk is detected. Then it would probably ask for the password, then send relevant DBUS message requesting mounting the drive. I could be wrong, this is just speculation, but perhaps it gives you ideas about where to search for more information.

Answer (score 0):

#### To restrict any external USB storage media,

blacklist the driver responsible for supporting USB mass storage.

For example on Ubuntu, add the following lines to the end of the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

```
# disable usb storage access
blacklist usb_storage
```

On subsequent reboots usb storage devices will not be supported until the driver is loaded first (which only a superuser can do).

*Note that ONLY a superuser account can modify this blacklist file in the first place.*

Now you could simply remove the kernel module for USB mass storage as a superuser

```
rmmod usb_storage
```

Only a superuser can now `modprobe` or `insmod` the usb storage driver to enable USB storage media.

> One could write a GUI application running as a superuser that can prompt the user for a password and load/remove the `usb_storage.ko` as required.

*Do note that the application now becomes the target of attacks and depending on how it stores/verifies the password, it could be easily bypassed by a reasonably motivated "attacker".*

Also note that with this approach, it is an ALL or nothing feature i.e. once authenticated, then any USB storage media will be accessible on all USB ports until they are disabled back again by unloading the `usb_storage.ko` module.

---

#### To protect data within external USB media,

start using encrypted storage devices with the help of [`dm-crypt`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption) or [`ecryptfs`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs).

Essentially you need to encrypt the external USB storage media first. Subsequently when it is connected to the system, depending upon the configuration:

- the user has to run a couple of commands on the terminal (and provide the password)

  *OR*
- the system prompts for the password and once provide, attempts to mount the encrypt disk.

> Refer to the following [**wiki**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage) for a step-by-step guide to creating encrypted external disks, and configuring an Ubuntu Linux machine such that it prompts for password and auto-mounts encrypted disks when connected.

Comment: How do you propose he does the encryption part, in practice? Say, he has an USB stick from a friend, and wants to get files from it, just wants a password prompt when inserting it to his computer. How should he do the encryption?

Comment: @hyde You are right. I have updated the answer to handle restricting access to **ALL** USB storage media and allow enabling it upon authentication.

Comment: I have to white list selected USB storage devices. If I remove usb_storage.ko then it will not allow to plug and use selected USB storage devices.